# Can you use SBS 2011 Sharepoint Foundation to collaborate with external users?

Tags: sharepoint, windows-sbs

We are thinking about upgrading to SBS 2011. We would also like a way to collaborate with our external clients using Sharepoint Foundation, which is built into SBS 2011. Is this possible? I know in full Sharepoint you can publish client facing sites where you can share documents back and forth, but I wasn't sure if Sharepoint Foundation could do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technology supports it but the SharePoint Foundation License does not.  In order to set up this type of scenario you would need a license for ***SharePoint Server 2010 for Internet Sites***.

Check out [Microsoft's SharePoint Licensing Q&A](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/Pages/Licensing-Details.aspx) for more details.

Comment: As long as they're "countable" users, you can use server + CAL licensing: Can also be used for external users if they are countable and CALs can be assigned to specific people.

Comment: I believe that only applies if they are licensed for Standard or Enterprise, not Foundation.

Comment: Indeed - right above it in the bullets: "Server plus CAL" (license).